# Nuxt auth doesn't set user from the WordPress API

Tags: wordpress, api, authentication, nuxt.js

I successfully get data from the WordPress rest API

[data from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN77Y.png)

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
                user: {url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me/', method: 'post', propertyName: false  }, 
                tokenRequired: true,
                tokenType: 'Bearer',
                globalToken: true,
            }
        }
    },
}
```

But in the index page view, isLogged is always false.

```
computed: {
    isLogged() {
        return this.$auth.loggedIn;
    }
},
```

In the nuxt.config.js target is set to 'static'.

I have no idea where is the problem and how could I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I install the wrong module. If anyone got the same problem, make sure you install '@nuxtjs/auth'